# Regarding the shift from Present Perfect to Past Simple

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

If in the second of the two sentences, "Mrs. Jervis, thank you for all your kindness. Heaven reward you for the good you have done me.", the "have done me" part gets changed into "you did me", does it still make sense but with a changed meaning, or does it no longer have any sense?

As I understand, in the original sentence, what is meant is that some Mrs. Jervis has done (probably not on a single, but on many occasions), a lot of good things towards the speaker. So, if we tried to insert a tense-marking word/phrase, it probably would be something like "Heaven reward you for the good you have done me over all these years". Am I right to believe that something like this tenses marker is implied, but omitted because it is understood?

Following this logic, if we changed the original sentence into "Heaven reward you for the good you did me", would it mean that Mrs. Jervis did something good on some particular occasion, which is meant, but not mentioned?

Also, I have read that the Present Perfect tense makes the verb bear some relevance to the present moment, while the Past Simple tense does no such a thing. Thus, would the "Heaven reward you for the good you did me" sound neglectful, as it refers to the good deeds as to something that bears no relevance to the present?

I am sorry if this is a bit of a jumble, but I just got a bit too confused over this topic...
I found the original sentence via the British National Corpus (I was looking for some sentences to study to understand grammar better, but it seems now I have more questions than answers ) .

Thank you for taking the time to read all of this

Comment: As a British English speaker, I agree completely with your first three paragraphs. No, using the simple past tense wouldn't sound 'neglectful' in the way you suggest.